# Given two points endpoints of circle chord find the locus of midpoint

Tags: circles, locus

> $A(2 \cos \theta_1 , 2 \sin \theta_1)$ and $B(2 \cos \theta_2 , 2 \sin \theta_2)$ are two end points of a variable chord $AB$ of the circle, and $M$ is the midpoint of the chord. Suppose that the slope of the chord $AB$ is $\textbf{always}$ equal to $m$. Find the equation of the locus of $M$.

While trying to solve the problem I found that:

- Equation of the circle is $x^2 + y^2 = 4$
- Coordinates of chord midpoint $M$ are $\left( \cos \theta_1 +  \cos \theta_2 , \sin \theta_1 + \sin \theta_2 \right)$
- Slope of chord AB is $m = 
  \dfrac{\sin \theta_2 - \sin \theta_1}{ \cos \theta_2 - \cos \theta_1}$

What should I do to get the solution: $x + my = 0$ ?

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough info for an unique answer. If $L = |AB|$ is arbitrary, $M$ can be any point of the unit disk. If $L$ is fixed, the locus will be a circle whose radius depends of $L$.

Comment: @achillehui The only additional info I have is that the parametric equations of the circle are $x=2 \cos \theta$ and $y=2 \sin \theta$, as well as that we should suppose that the slope of AB is $\textbf{always}$ equal to $m$ (calculated above). Hope this helps. The answer in the book is $x+my=0$.

Comment: If you rotate everything by a suitable angle, you can make all chords horizontal (i.e. slope $=0$). The locus is the diameter parallel to $y$-axis. Rotate it back, the locus is  a diameter with slope $-\frac1m$ (the locus is perpendicular to the chords). i.e. $y = -\frac1m x \iff x + my = 0$.

Comment: Well, I am not sure that the circle can rotate... But anyway thanks for your effort, maybe I figure out something

Comment: An alternative way to think about this is look at everything from a new coordinate system where the new $x$-axis is parallel to the chords.

Comment: Is there anything about $\theta_1, \theta_2$ that you haven't mentioned? Because if these two angles are arbitrary, then achille hui is right, Every point inside the circle is the midpoint of the chord for some value of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$. Your "additional info" is not additional at all, but simple repeats what is in your post.

Comment: There is nothing about the angles. The only thing that I didn't mention is that there is another circle $C_2$ whose parametric equations are $x=3t$ and $y=3t^2$. I have calculated that these two circles intersect in $\left(\sqrt{3}, 1 \right) $ and $\left( -\sqrt{3}, 1 \right) $, which is correct according to the book. But I don't believe that this is related to my question, maybe I am wrong?

Comment: You mentioned in an earlier comment that the slope of the chords is always equal to $m$, i.e., that they are parallel. This is an important piece of information. Please edit your question to include this constraint instead of simply leaving it buried in a comment that others who might want to help you with this will likely miss (and have).

Comment: @amd Done! Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slope of the line of midpoints must be $-\dfrac 1m$ and the line must contain the origin. So the equation is $y = -\dfrac 1mx$ or $x+my=0$

---

You know that
\begin{align}
   M_{1,2} 
   &= \left(\cos\theta_1 +  \cos\theta_2 , \ 
            \sin\theta_1 + \sin\theta_2 \right) \\
   &= \left(2\cos\dfrac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2} 
             \cos\dfrac{\theta_1-\theta_2}{2} , \ 
            2\sin\dfrac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2} 
             \cos\dfrac{\theta_1-\theta_2}{2} \right) 
\end{align}

We also know that $M_0 =(0,0)$ is the midpoint of the line with slope $m$ that passes through the origin. The slope of the line through $M_0$ and $M_{1,2}$ is

$m' = \dfrac
   {2\sin\dfrac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}\cos\dfrac{\theta_1-\theta_2}{2}}
   {2\cos\dfrac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}\cos\dfrac{\theta_1-\theta_2}{2}}
 = \tan \dfrac{\theta_1+\theta_2}{2}
 $

You also know that

\begin{align}
   m 
   &= \dfrac{\sin \theta_2 - \sin \theta_1}
            { \cos \theta_2 - \cos \theta_1} \\
   &= \dfrac{ 2 \sin \dfrac{\theta_2 - \theta_1}{2}
                \cos \dfrac{\theta_2 + \theta_1}{2}}
            {-2 \sin \dfrac{\theta_2 - \theta_1}{2}
                \sin \dfrac{\theta_2 + \theta_1}{2}} \\
   &= -\cot \dfrac{\theta_2 + \theta_1}{2}
\end{align}

So, for all $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ that represent the angles corresponding to the endpoints of a line with slope $m$ intersecting the circle $x^2+y^2 = 4$, $m \cdot m' = -1$.

In other words, the locus of the bisectors is a line with slope $-\dfrac 1m$.

Comment: This looks like hell. Thanks a lot, I would never come to this point alone

Answer (score 1):

The parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ serve no useful purpose other than allowing you to find a Cartesian equation for the circle, so now that you’ve done that, let’s forget about them. The endpoints of the chords are the intersections of the line $y=mx+b$ with the circle $x^2+y^2=4$, with fixed slope $m$ and variable $y$-intercept $b$. Some straightforward algebra yields the points $$\left({-mb\pm\sqrt{4(1+m^2)-b^2} \over 1+m^2}, {b\pm m\sqrt{4(1+m^2)-b^2} \over 1+m^2}\right)$$ and so $$M(b) = \left(-{mb\over 1+m^2}, {b\over 1+m^2}\right).$$ Eliminate $b$ to get a Cartesian equation for this curve. Note, though, that not all values of $b$ are valid—most lines won’t intersect the circle. For the line to have two intersection points with real coordinates, we must have $-2\sqrt{1+m^2}\lt b\lt 2\sqrt{1+m^2}$.

Incidentally, this is a special case of a general theorem about midpoints of parallel chords of an ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

Think of A, B on the circle (center C), at angle $\theta_1, \theta_2$
Thus, AB's midpoint M, inside circle, angle = ${\theta_1 +\theta_2 \over 2}$

AB perpendicular to MC, with angle to the x-axis: $\theta_{AB} = 90° + {\theta_1 +\theta_2 \over 2}$

$$m = \tan(\theta_{AB}) =  \tan(90° + {\theta_1 +\theta_2 \over 2})
= -\cot({\theta_1 +\theta_2 \over 2}) $$